# StreamWriter Text File name must include hour, minute and second

Tags: vb.net

Run following code and see that you have text file on the desktop named `MyLogFile 08.04.2017`

```
    Dim Log As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MyLogFile " & System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") & ".txt", False)
    Log.WriteLine("Hello")
    Log.Close()
```

I had wanted to change file name from `MyLogFile 08.04.2017` to `MyLogFile 08.04.2017 07:50:59` but it is not possible because `:` is not allowed.

Now, I want to change file name from `MyLogFile 08.04.2017` to `MyLogFile 08.04.2017 07.50.59` thanks to your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
Dim Folder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim FileName As String = "MyLogFile " & DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss") & ".txt"
Dim Log As System.IO.StreamWriter
Log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(Folder, FileName), False)
Log.WriteLine("Hello")
Log.Close()
```

Comment: If I run this code mornings hour shows `07`. If I run this code evenings hour shows again `07`. But I want `07` mornings, `19` evenings. Possible?

Comment: Yes, change `hh` to `HH`. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.7) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend that, when including dates and time in file and folder names, that you go from most significant to least significant.  The reason for that is that then alphabetical and chronological order will match.  Personally, I don't use separators at all so that would be:

```
Log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                                                             String.Format("MyLogFile.{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.txt",
                                                                           Date.Now),
                                                False)
```

If you really want to do it your way then it would be:

```
Log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
                                                             String.Format("MyLogFile {0:dd.MM.yyyy HH.mm.ss}.txt",
                                                                           Date.Now),
                                                False)
```

You simply change the format specifier as needed.